# User (PR_DISPLAT_TYPE) DisplayType using Redemption MAPITable

Tags: office365, mapi, outlook-redemption

I want to get Office365 users DisplayType using Redemption MAPITable.
but Redemption MAPITable does not give the correct results for Office365 Users DisplayType.

Without MAPITable, I am able to find it but it is a very slow process.

When I am using Redemption MAPITable the result is different and returns the same result for all users.

where is the issue? or Is there another MAPI property to find it?

Both process which i am using are :

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession");
         set AddrList = Session.Addressbook.Gal;
         set AddrEntries = AddrList.AddressEntries;
         set AddrEntry  = AddrEntries.GetFirst;
         int k =0;
         while (AddrEntry!= NULL)
         { k= AddrEntry.DisplayType;//Result is DT_MAILUSER(0) and DT_REMOTE_MAILUSER(6)
           AddrEntry = AddrEntries.GetNext();} 

         Above method give the correct result verify by outlookspy.            

        _IMAPITable        table;
         table = AddrEntries.GetMAPITable();
         _RecordsetPtr pRstAuthors("ADODB.Recordset");
         pRstAuthors = table.ExecSQL(_T("SELECT \"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39000003\" from list"));
         int k=0;
         while (!pRstAuthors->EndOfFile)
         { k = pRstAuthors->GetFields()->Item[0]->GetValue();//Result DT_MAILUSER(0)for All User
           k = pRstAuthors->GetFields()->Item[0]->Value.intVal;//Result DT_MAILUSER(0) for All User
           pRstAuthors->MoveNext();}
```

All users same result. which is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: So what is the problem? Are the properties not available in the MAPI table? Can you see them in OutlookSpy (GetContentsTable tab of the GAL address book container)?

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for reply. Problem is that using mapi table I am not able to differentiate inDT_MAILUSER(0) and DT_REMOTE_MAILUSER(6) because I am getting same result 0 , while outlook spy differentiate it o and 6.

Comment: Hi Dmitry I want to differentiate office 365 active and non active users using MAPI table so which MAPI property use to know that office365 user is active or non active.   Thanks

Comment: Does OutlookSpy show DT_MAILUSER vs  DT_REMOTE_MAILUSER in the GetContentsTable tab or when you open the address etnry? In teh former case, your code that calls ExecSQL should show the same result.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for reply. I have checkd in outlookspy as follow :
IAddrBook->ResolveName->CallIDdrBook::ResolveName->Show More Names-> Then Select the Mailbox ->Then check the PR_DISPLAY_TYPE property (Then value is 0 and 6)

But If I follow different path as you:
IAddrBook->Open container->Global Address List->(IAB Cintainer-Global AddressList) GetContentsTable -> Then Select mailbox-> Then check the PR_DISPLAY_TYPE property (Then value is 0 for both mailbox).

Which is correct ?
How I can differentiate office 365 Active and Non Active  users ?

Comment: Hmmm.. Would PR_DISPLAY_TYPE_EX help?